# Issue with parsing a function in Python (optionally with pyparsing)

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, bnf

I'm using the pyparsing library to parse a python-like programming language.  I seem to be having trouble figuring out how to translate the BNF grammar into executable code.

My script is obviously more complex than this, but I've distilled the problem to a few lines:

```
arg_or_func_name = Word(alphanums + '_')
expr = Forward()
func = expr + Literal('(') + Literal(')')
expr << (arg_or_func_name | func)
statement = expr + Literal(';')

parsed = statement.parseString('func_a();')
```

I want this to parse as `[('expr', [('func', ['func_a', '(', ')')])]), ';']`.  Instead, it causes the error `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ";"`, I assume because it greedily considers func_a as an arg_or_func_name, and then disregards the parentheses.

However, when I reverse the order of the expr statement and change it to

```
expr << (func | arg_or_func_name)
```

or when I do

```
expr << (func ^ arg_or_func_name)
```

I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error; apparently searching in this order results in some infinite recursive loop.

I would like for my program to match the longest string possible (specifically, all of func_a()), but in a way that does not cause an infinite loop.  Is this possible?

I would much prefer to continue using pyparsing, so answers using that library would be greatly preferred, but I'd also appreciate any answers using other python tools for translating BNF grammars.

Comment: Can func really start with an expr? I'm pretty sure that if you do something like this in C, for instance, the expr has to be in ()'s. Then you could define func as `(arg_or_func_name | '(' + expr + ')') + '(' + ')'`

Comment: `(arg_or_func_name | '(' + expr + ')') + '(' + ')'` does the job - thanks!  (Although I'm pretty sure in python func can start with an expr.  Consider f = lambda i: lambda j: i + j, then you can call f(2)(3) and get 5.  Or if you have x = [sum], you can call x[0]([1,2,3]) and get 6)

Comment: That is not quite the same as an expr - if a is your lambda and b is None, you can't write `a or b()`, it has to be `(a or b)()`.